# Accessing server with .local address

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server, osx-snow-leopard

I just setup a new Mac OS X Server, named it myserver.local. I have a couple websites that I'm running from it as a webserver and am trying to access the server as such: http://pilotserver.local/index.php

This generally seems to work but resolving the address is taking *forever*. I could easily type in the IP address and it resolves instantly but it's much neater if I use the local address.

Any recommendations? Changing the .host file isn't an option either.

Dave

Answer (score 2):

Install Bonjour on all the windows and linux machines... (on Linux sometimes called ZeroConf/MDNSResolver)
Mac clients should resolve it quick enough, don't they?

Comment: Agree with that, .local names should be resolved using Bonjour, no need for DNS or hosts files.

Answer (score 1):

If this is one or two hosts that won't be accessed from anywhere else, use /etc/hosts

You could setup  a local nameserver on the machine, but it sounds overkill unless you want to learn about DNS.

So

**/etc/hosts**

```
w.x.y.z pilotserver.local
```

Then you can use Named Virtual Hosts on Apache with the ServerName set to pilotserver.local

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you mean the same machine with pilotserver.local and myserver.local. In case you do, having your server set either as a dns-server using resolv.conf or as a static dns entry using hosts, it shouldn't be a problem.

Maybe you have to check whether your server software is the reason for the delay or it's actually the name resolving part. I once had a problem similar to this one, and it was caused by a misconfigured dns server on the server side, so maybe thats a point worth checking.

Comment: So I added pilotserver.local to the resolv.conf with 192.168.0.1 on the server side. I noticed that there are some other nameservers listed there. Looks good. The question is do I have to restart or something to get it listening in on it now?

I doubt it's the server itself when I can use other commands like afp://pilotserver.local - they work instantly. Just seems to be an HTTP issue...